# Twitter gather in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, twitter, network-programming, tweets

I would like to gather in postgreSQL tweets from a particular geographic area (eg filtration after. Area bounded by coordinates). Is there a project that I could use? I saw Library twitter4j if she allows powering to build such a tool? I'd rather use the already finished, but I can also write such.

Comment: Are you looking for (1) A way in PostgreSQL to filter by coordinates or (2) a way to classify tweets you have with coordinates or (3) both?

Comment: I'm looking for tool which get tweets from selected area, and save result to PostgreSQL